# TypeError: THREE.OrbitControls is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am starting with three.js. And now I find an issue and need help. Look simple but I don't find a good answer. The problem is: Even declaring the use of OrbitControls.js (CODE1), Even if it's showed in THREE tree at DOM (Figure 1). When I try to use the constructor (CODE 2) I am receiving the error:" TypeError: THREE.OrbitControls is not a constructor" FIGURE2.

```
CODE1 :***index.html***
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
            canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

       <script src="js/libs/three.min.js"></script>
       <script src="js/cena.js"></script>
       <script src="js/libs/AxisHelper.js"></script>
       <script src="js/libs/GridHelper.js"></script>
       <script src="js/libs/OrbitControls.js"></script> 

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: THE THREE tree at DOM]

```
CODE2***:cena.js***

var cena = new THREE.Scene();

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

var renderizador = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});

renderizador.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

document.body.appendChild( renderizador.domElement );
//----------------------------


var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 3, 1, 2 );

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );

var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

var axisHelper = new THREE.AxisHelper( 5 );
cena.add( axisHelper )
var tamanho = 10;
var elementos = 10;
var grid = new THREE.GridHelper(tamanho,elementos);
cena.add(grid);

cena.add( cube );

camera.position.z = 10;
camera.position.y = 10;
camera.position.x = 5;

var lookat_vector = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0);
camera.lookAt(lookat_vector);
//++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

var controle = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderizador.domElement);

var render = function () {
        requestAnimationFrame( render );
        controle.update();
        cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
        cube.rotation.y +=0.01;
        cube.rotation.z +=0.03;

        renderizador.render(cena, camera);
        //controle.update();
    };

render();
```

[image: Error]

Answer (score 6):

You need to include the libs and put your `cena.js` script at the end.
Script tags are loaded synchronously.

```
   <script src="js/libs/three.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/libs/AxisHelper.js"></script>
   <script src="js/libs/GridHelper.js"></script>
   <script src="js/libs/OrbitControls.js"></script>
   <script src="js/cena.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to include OBJLoader.js in the script tags prior to creating THREE.OrbitalControls.